# Rao-Blackwellisation using non-sufficient statistics

Tags: estimation, inference, conditional-expectation, sufficient-statistics, rao-blackwell

The following is given as a remark in chapter 7 of [Introduction to mathematical statistics Hogg and Craig, 8th edition](https://amzn.to/3Jdx1n2). (It is mentioned as "Remark 7.3.1")

[image]

Now, I *do* understand that the distribution of $Y_1|Y_3$ would contain $\theta$ *compulsorily* (because $Y_3$ is not a sufficient statistic).
*But I do not understand why $\theta $ has to be present *compulsorily* in the conditional mean $X=\mathbb E[\varphi(Y_1)|Y_3]$.*

I can agree to the statement "$\theta$ ***can*** be present in $X$". But I do not understand why $\theta$ ***has*** to be present in $X$.
Because the distribution of $Y_1|Y_3$ could contain parameters other than $\theta$ also. So, it is possible for $\mathbb E[\varphi(Y_1)|Y_3]=X$ to contain those other parameters(and not contain $\theta$).

So why is it always true that $\theta $ will be present in $X$?

EDIT:-

I'm not sure, but I think that (going by the definition of sufficiency given in Hogg and Craig) the concept of sufficiency is defined only when the pdf of the random sample ( i.e. $f_X(x;\theta)$ ) has exactly one *unknown* parameter (namely $\theta$).
If that's the case, then the only unknown parameter that the distribution of $Y_1|Y_3$ contains is $\theta$. 
Also note that $X=\mathbb E[\varphi(Y_1)|Y_3]$, cannot be a constant that is not equal to $\theta$( because then $\mathbb{E}[X]\neq \theta$ )
So, If $X$ is a constant then $X=\theta$. But what if $X$ is not a constant?
So, in the case when $X$ is not a constant, why should $\theta$ be present in $X$, compulsorily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Counter-example:** If [one considers the case](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/503933/7224) of a sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ from a $N(\theta,\theta^2)$ distribution, a minimal sufficient statistic is
$$T=\left(\sum_i X_i,\sum_i(X_i-\bar X_n)^2\right)$$
Now $\varphi(T)=\bar X_n$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ *that is not sufficient*. But the conditional expectation
$$\mathbb E_\theta[\varphi(T)|\varphi(T)]=\varphi(T)$$
does not involve $\theta$.